# Controlling the simplification of special functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I evaluated the following function:

```
Psi[u_, t_, z_] := 
 Integrate[(1 - Exp[-u s^2 - t s]) s^(-z - 1), {s, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {u > 0 , t > 0 , 0 < z < 1}]
```

obtaining

```
(*  -2^z u^(z/2) Gamma[-z] HypergeometricU[-(z/2), 1/2, t^2/(4 u)] *)
```

Then if I specialised for the case $z=1/2$, obtaining the following (even after applying `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`).

```
Psi[u, t, 1/2]

(* 
  2 Sqrt[2 π] u^(1/4) HypergeometricU[-(1/4), 1/2, t^2/(4 u)]
 *)
```

Instead, if I rewrite explicitly the same function setting $z=1/2$ I obtain the result stated in terms of a different special function:

```
Psi2[u_, t_] := 
 Integrate[(1 - Exp[-u s^2 - t s]) s^(-1 - 0.5), {s, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {u > 0 , t > 0 }]
```

obtaining

```
(* 
 2.45083 u^0.25 Hypergeometric1F1[-0.25, 0.5, t^2/(4 u)] + 
 (1.8128 t^1. Hypergeometric1F1[0.25, 1.5, t^2/(4 u)])/u^0.25
*)
```

and the result does not change even applying `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`. I thought that the results were shown in terms of the "simpler" special function for Mathematica and I do not understand why I get two different expressions.

So now I wonder if the result could be stated in terms of what are for me simpler special functions (e.g., Bessel functions). More generally, it is possible to force Mathematica to write the results in terms of another special function of interest to the user?

I am new to Mathematica so any suggestion or tutorial related to my task is very appreciated.

Comment: Using `FunctionExpand` with `z = 1/2` returns a result in BesselK functions.

Comment: Thank you @BillWatts! I did not know this function. Are there similar functions to try in order to rewrite a result in terms of another special function? Or better does exist a general strategy to force Mathematica to display some equivalent results? Until now I find `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Refine` and, thanks to you, `FunctionExpand`.

Comment: You could look at the tutorial "Working with Special Functions" in the MMA help pages

Comment: Thanks @BillWatts

Answer (score 4):

The integral in the OP can be expressed as a Mellin transform:

```
MellinTransform[1 - Exp[-u s^2 - t s], s, -z] // Expand
   1/2 t u^(-1/2 + z/2) Gamma[1/2 - z/2] Hypergeometric1F1[1/2 - z/2, 3/2, t^2/(4 u)] -
   1/2 u^(z/2) Gamma[-z/2] Hypergeometric1F1[-z/2, 1/2, t^2/(4 u)]
```

---

> I do not understand why I get two different expressions.

There is [a relationship](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E42) between the Tricomi function `HypergeometricU[a, b, z]` and the Kummer function `Hypergeometric1F1[a, b, z]` when `b` is not an integer:

```
Activate[First[
         MathematicalFunctionData[Entity["MathematicalFunction", "HypergeometricU"], 
                                  "AlternativeRepresentations"]][-z/2, 1/2, t^2/(4 u)]]
   HypergeometricU[-z/2, 1/2, t^2/(4 u)] ==
   -((Sqrt[π] Sqrt[t^2/u] Hypergeometric1F1[1/2 - z/2, 3/2, t^2/(4 u)])/Gamma[-z/2]) +
   (Sqrt[π] Hypergeometric1F1[-z/2, 1/2, t^2/(4 u)])/Gamma[1/2 - z/2]
```

`FunctionExpand[]` can then be used if one wishes an expression in terms of other functions, e.g.

```
MellinTransform[1 - Exp[-u s^2 - t s], s, -z] /. z -> 1/2 // FunctionExpand // Simplify
   (E^(t^2/(8 u)) π (t Sqrt[t^2/u] Sqrt[u] BesselI[-1/4, t^2/(8 u)] -
    (t^2 - 4 u) BesselI[1/4, t^2/(8 u)] +
    t (-Sqrt[t^2/u] Sqrt[u] BesselI[3/4, t^2/(8 u)] + 
       t BesselI[5/4, t^2/(8 u)])))/(2 Sqrt[2] (t^2/u)^(1/4) u^(3/4))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Psi[u_, t_, z_] := 
 Integrate[(1 - Exp[-u s^2 - t s]) s^(-z - 1), {s, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {u > 0, t > 0, 0 < z < 1}]

Psi[u, t, 1/2]

(* 2 Sqrt[2 π] u^(1/4) HypergeometricU[-(1/4), 1/2, t^2/(4 u)] *)
```

The difference that you observed resulted from using `0.5` rather than `1/2`

```
Psi[u, t, 0.5]

(* 2.45083 u^0.25 Hypergeometric1F1[-0.25, 0.5, t^2/(4 u)] + (
 1.8128 t^1. Hypergeometric1F1[0.25, 1.5, t^2/(4 u)])/u^0.25 *)
```

The result for `Psi[u, t, 0.5]` is identical with `Psi2[u, t]`

```
Psi2[u_, t_] := 
  Integrate[(1 - Exp[-u s^2 - t s]) s^(-1 - 0.5), {s, 0, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {u > 0, t > 0}];

Psi2[u, t] === Psi[u, t, 0.5]

(* True *)
```

As pointed out by Bill Watts, the [`HypergeometricU`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricU.html) can be expressed in terms of [`BesselK`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselK.html)

```
Psi3[u_, t_] = 
 Psi[u, t, 1/2] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify[#, {u > 0, t > 0}] &

(* (E^(t^2/(8 u)) t^(
 3/2) (BesselK[1/4, t^2/(8 u)] + BesselK[3/4, t^2/(8 u)]))/(2 Sqrt[u]) *)
```